# Get properties from gradle.build in Java

Tags: java, android, gradle

Is there a way to access the `version` property (or any other property for that matter) in `gradle.build` from Java - like what Android does with `BuildConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call 
`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` to get the version name specified in the `build.gradle` file.

Like that, you can also access other variables defined in the build file.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. I tried it on a project earlier today and BuildConfig couldn't be found, but now with another project its there! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try rebuilding the first project. It should be there. :)

Comment: Will try it when I get the opportunity! Thanks again! :)